# Google maps error after some time that is fixed 00.00 Pacific time

Tags: google-maps, google-api

We are querying google maps service for static map image that stops working after some time (usually later in a day) with "StaticMaperror/Signature" error but we are not using Signature.

The problem is usually automatically gone after 00.00 AM (Pacific time) next day. There are no limits/thresholds configured on Google console portal for this API/key and it's not clear why we are getting this error after some time as it clearly looks like connected to some threshold/requests limit on on Google console portal

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=USA&zoom3&size=395x272&maptype=roadmap&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score -1):

Based on this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/usage-and-billing#authenticating-requests), you are only allowed up to **25,0000 unsigned(no digital signature) static maps requests per day**.
It is possible that you are hitting this limit which causes you to get those errors.

For more than requests 25, 000 requests, you are required to include a **digital signature** in your Static Maps API request. Here's a guide on [how to generate a digital signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#gen-sig).

If you are still having issues or concerns regarding your specific Google Maps project, you can always reach out to [Google Maps Platform support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support).

Hope this helps!